# conio.h под linux

Tags: c++

Добрый день, недавно начал осваивать c++ и сталкнулся с такой проблемой. Я работаю под Linux Ubuntu и библиотеки conio.h я так понял нет. Подскажите как разрешить данную проблему. Мб можно скачать библиотеку или есть аналоги. Заранее спасибо. На гугл не направлять я там был...

Answer (score 4):

1. [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) - работа с псевдографикой в терминале;
2. [linux-conioh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/) - реализация conio.h для linux на основе ncurses.

Answer (score 2):

[Пара](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) [манов](http://alexber220.narod.ru/ncurses/) по ncurses.