# Linux: снова вопрос про аналог conio.h (неблокирующий ввод с клавиатуры под linux)

Tags: c++, linux, c, ubuntu, ncurses

Господа,

мой вопрос настолько классический, что прямо смешно. Он называется "неблокирующий ввод с клавиатуры под linux".

Я хочу иметь возможность в программе на C спросить "верни мне, пожалуйста, код нажатой клавиши, а если ничего не нажато - верни -1".

Под виндой именно такую функциональность даёт `include <conio.h> ... int kb=getch();`.

Конечно, я прочитал [вот этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input) и [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16368/conio-h-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-linux)  топики и поэкспериментировал с теми способами, котрые там советуют.

У них есть один недостаток: они "ломают вывод на экран" при помощи простого printf().

То есть, по меткому выражению одного из комментаторов, используя ncurses вы получаете "всё или ничего". То есть, если Вы подключили ncurses - нужно забыть про printf и использовать специфичные для ncurses способы вывода на экран.

С советом, в котором приводится код для getch()

```
    int getch()
    {
        int r;
        unsigned char c;
        if ((r = read(0, &c, sizeof(c))) < 0) {
            return r;
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }
```

(это кусочек из полного кода, который доступен по первой ссылке) всё немного лучше, но всё равно, при попытке в цикле вводить симолы и печатаь их коды на экране возникает вот такая картина:

код main'а: (выше мейна написан целиком тот код, который советуют в самом популярном ответе по первой ссылке)

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf("Hello again!\n");
        set_conio_terminal_mode();

        while (!kbhit()) {
            /* do some work */
        }

        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
            int kb = getch(); /* consume the character */
            printf ("kb=%d\n", kb); 
        }

        printf ("Bye!\n");
    }
```

картинка на экране:

[image: как съезжает каретка при каждой печати]

Ну, то есть, при выполнении каждого printf положение "виртуальной каретки" смещается.

Нельзя ли с этим как то побороться? может, есть способ, как вводить символы с клавиатуры и при этом нормально пользоваться printf?

Comment: Вам не стоит путать ввод с клавиатуры и ввод через стандартный поток ввода.

Comment: Если подойти к делу серьезно, то для начала читаете [man termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). Если по быстрому, попробуйте в  new_termios установить ONLCR  -- `(XSI) Map NL to CR-NL on output.`  (всех деталей, к сожалению, я сейчас уже не помню)

Comment: @user7860670 - извините, а когда Вы пишете про то, что не стоит путать, а не могли бы Вы немного расшифровать? может, я ломлюсь в открыытую дверь, и всё можно делать проще?

Comment: @avp - спасибо большое за совет. Я попробовал "по быстрому" единственно пришедшим мне в голову способом - "struct termios new_termios;
    new_termios.c_cflag |= ONLCR;" - но это не привело к результату. Нем не менее, Ваш совет, возможно, поможет кому то, кто поумнее меня. Буду искать обходной путь.

Comment: @S.H., вообще-то я бы распечатал, полученные в tcgetattr элементы структуры и посмторел на них. Можно попробовать для начала просто сбросить ICANON и ECHO. А еще можно поиграться в терминале с stty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы меня устыдили и я быстренько попробовал вспомнить.

У меня

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-70-generic #78~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 14:10:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia \n \l

avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Вот программка для печати кодов вводимых символов

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  struct termios t, old;

  tcgetattr(0, &t);
  old = t;
  t.c_lflag &= ~(ISIG | ICANON | ECHO);
  t.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  t.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);

  char c;
  while (read(0, &c, 1) == 1) {
    printf("'%c' is %d 0%03o 0x%02x\n",
       c, c, c, c);
    if (c == 4) // ^D is EOF as usual
      break;
  }
    

  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Я немного подолбил по клавишам и кажется, что  у меня она вполне работает:

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c && ./a.out
'1' is 49 0061 0x31
'2' is 50 0062 0x32
'3' is 51 0063 0x33
'
' is 10 0012 0x0a
'
' is 10 0012 0x0a
'
' is 10 0012 0x0a
'
 ' is 11 0013 0x0b
'q' is 113 0161 0x71
'w' is 119 0167 0x77
'e' is 101 0145 0x65
'' is 127 0177 0x7f
'!' is 33 0041 0x21
'@' is 64 0100 0x40
'$' is 36 0044 0x24
'' is 4 0004 0x04
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Comment: avp - Супер! я совершенно не хотел вас стыдить, и Вы сделали гораздо больше того, на что я мог рассчитывать. У меян просто уже к концу дня мозги сворачивались в трубочку, и не было особо идей, как двигаться дальше. Огромное Вам спасибо не только от меня, но и от тех, кто когда нибудь прочитает Ваш ответ!

Comment: Все ОК (насчет устыдили это я, конечно, преувеличил для красного словца -))

Comment: на мой вкус `ISIG` всё же лишний... ну и я бы ещё добавил, что с таким способом много других подводных камней...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, хотите по ^Z в фон отправляться?

Comment: скорее по `^C` завершать и нормальный `EOF` посылать... с `^Z` тоже проблемы будут — `bash` сбрасывает флаги терминала и для него обработчик `SIGCONT` придётся писать... а чтобы оставаться чистым, надо ещё и `SIGINT`'а обработчик сделать, чтоб в нём флаги чистить на всякий пожарный... в общем это всё быстро выходит за размер минимального примера =)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вот чтобы всего этого избежать я и сбрасываю ISIG. Если хотите по ^C завершаться, то `if (c == 3) break;`

Comment: нум... я понимаю... просто заметил, что на практике так делать не надо...

Comment: Я не понял тогда вопрос. **S.H.** просил вернуть -1 при отсутсвии нажатий в буфере. А вы делаете просто **getchar** с блокировкой. Что тут радоваться?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, основная проблема у него была в сползании текста при выводе \n. Он же разумный человек, наверняка сам сообразил, что для проверки наличия данных надо перед read использовать select или ioctl